# Data Type Mismatch error while using the SQL Update query

Tags: sql, excel, vba

I am using SQL update query in VBA and I am getting the datatype mismatch error. I know that error is basically because of the column spare part. The spare part column contains numeric and alphanumeric values.

```vb
Public Function UpdateDistinctColumnFRNumberBasis()

    StrInvoiceNumber = "109839-01"
    FRSparepartNumber = "FT7119907459"
    MergedInvoiceFile  = "/test.xlsx"
    
    
    Dim objConn As Object
    Dim objRecordSet As Object
    
    Set objConn = CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
    Set objRecCmd = CreateObject("ADODB.Command")
    Set objRecCmd_Update = CreateObject("ADODB.Command")
    
    objConn.Open ("Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=" & _
             MergedInvoiceFile & ";Extended Properties=""Excel 8.0;""")
    
    strSQL =  " Update [Tabelle1$] SET [Status] = 'Include' Where " & _
    "([RECHNR] ='" & StrInvoiceNumber & "' AND [Sparepart] = " & FRSparepartNumber & ")"
    
    objConn.Execute strSQL
    
    objConn.Close

End Function
```

Comment: If `Sparepart` contains a mix of datatypes then the driver may have assigned it as "text" so you'd need quotes around the value.  You can check by running a select on the table and checking the datatype of that field in the recordset.

Comment: Perhaps, maybe, provide us with the actual error? I also strongly suggest reading about parameterized queries, before strings with quotes, etc, bite you; https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/ado/guide/data/command-object-parameters?view=sql-server-ver15

Comment: Hey I am using this query only , strSQL =  " Update [Tabelle1$] SET [Status] = 'Include' Where ([RECHNR] ='" & StrInvoiceNumber & "' AND [Sparepart] = '" & FRSparepartNumber & "')" . I mean to say that I am using the quotes around FRSparepart Number. This is really strange because sometimes it work and sometimes I get this error

Comment: Update [Tabelle1$] SET [Status] = 'Include'  Where ([RECHNR] ='100530-01' AND [TEILENUMMER] = 'FT99995500527'). Data type mismatch in criteria expression.

Comment: As per my understanding datatype mismatch error comes when SQL is expected a string and we passing a number right ?  Here TEILENUMMER] = 'FT99995500527') , FT99995500527 is alphanumeric hence it is not a number. That is why I have used single quotes in the expression. I don't understand why I am getting this error

Comment: Run a select `select * from [Tabelle1$]` then loop over the Fields in the recordset `For Each f in rs.Fields: Debug.Print f.Name, f.Type : Next f` and cross-ref with https://www.devguru.com/content/technologies/ADO/field-type.html   That will tell you what type of data ADO thinks you have in each column and you can adjust your other SQL accordingly.

Comment: This was a great suggestion and I have implemented this , the data type is 202 for teilenummer column which is Null-terminated Unicode character string. Means this is String Data type as per ADO

Answer (score 0):

As commented, the partnumber is text, thus it must be quoted in the SQL:

```vb
    FRSparepartNumber = "FT7119907459"

    ' snip
    
   strSQL =  "Update [Tabelle1$] SET [Status] = 'Include' Where " & _
   "([RECHNR] = '" & StrInvoiceNumber & "' AND " & _
   "[Sparepart] = '" & FRSparepartNumber & "')"
```

Comment: I am using the quoted expression only , still I am getting the data mismatch error.

Comment: Then, I guess, one or more of the fields are of data type numeric, not text.

Comment: Yes the column has both string and numeric values

Comment: If both fields are of data type _Short Text_ the query criteria can't fail. Then it must be the `Status` field that is not _Short Text_.

Comment: Status is just blank column in which I am updating values , I don't think it is connected to the error somehow

Comment: "Think" doesn't work for debugging.  If all three fields are of data type _Short Text_, my query cannot fail with the error you report.

Comment: Can we connect over a zoom and debug together?

Comment: You could post a sample database at [UtterAccess](https://www.utteraccess.com/).

Comment: Okay , let me check